# How to use existing index to create conditional constraint

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, constraints

I have following index:

```
op.create_index(
    op.f("ix_order_company_id_email_lower"),
    "order",
    ["company_id", sa.text("lower(email)")],
    unique=False,
    postgresql_concurrently=True
)
```

Now I want to create a check constraint that is going to create sort of a 'unique' constraint for only specific type of orders.

```
op.execute(
    """ALTER TABLE order 
        ADD CONSTRAINT check_order_company_id_email_lower_type
        CHECK (type = 'AH01')
        NOT VALID"""
)
```

How can I add additional check to only apply to records in `ix_order_company_id_email_lower`?

EDIT: Basically this type of order can only be submitted once per email in a specific company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a partial unique index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON order (company_id, lower(email))
WHERE type = 'AH01';
```

Comment: Yep  `postgresql_where=(Order.type == "AH01"),` did the trick. thank you